# Sending Message In Android App

Tags: android, sms, messaging

I am working with message sending feature.

**sendButton click event :**

```
sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    approachThree();
                }
            });
```

**approachThree() method :**

```
private void approachThree() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode("9677353141")));
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Greetings!");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Its starts the Default message app. But,when I am back press from message app, it quits and **NOT** back to my app .

What stuff need to add in it ?

Comment: This works for me, i.e. back brings me back to my app. What's your default message app? The one that comes with stock android? Can you post your manifest?

Comment: try `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` instead of `startActivity(intent)`

Comment: also if your activity in the manifest has the attribute `android:noHistory="true"` remove it.

Comment: What kind of flags have you set for your Activity in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: @Nayra Ahmed I tried with startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode). And I didn't use the noHistory attribute.

Comment: @mach I didn't use any flags for this Activity.